# how to open excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer

I tried the below code to open excel file using javascript.
I tried in IE, Chrome, and Firefox but it's not opening the file.

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1">
  <input type=button onClick="test()" value="Open File">
  <br><br>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() {
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("teste.xlsx");
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is ActiveX enabled in the browser? I hope not, but...

Comment: thanks i enable that and its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveXObject is only supported by IE, other browsers don't support it.

```
Excel.Workbooks.Open("teste.xlsx");
```

There is no path specified for `teste.xlsx`, provide appropriate file path. The file should be accessed by the browser in the client system, so path should be set accordingly like `C:\\Temp\\teste.xlsx` (something similar with appropriate system drive).

Comment: The file should be in the client system and browser tries to access from client location only, so path should be set accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **Absolute Path** of the file you are trying to open

eg:

```
Excel.Workbooks.Open("E:\\test.xlsx");
```